# Проблемы с открытием файла PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, button, pyqt5

Пытаюсь присвоить кнопке функцию открытия файла и чтения в QTextEdit, но при нажатии кнопки графическая оболочка закрывается.

```
def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    import traceback
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))

    QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Error', text)
    quit()


import sys
sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication, QLineEdit, QDesktopWidget, QMessageBox, QToolTip, QPushButton,
                             QAction, QLabel, QGridLayout, QWidget, QTextEdit, QFileDialog)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QFont
from graph.run import run



class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.form_widget = FormWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.form_widget)

        exitAction = QAction(QIcon('D:/Programming/Python/mo-mo/GUI/icon/exit.png'), '&Exit', self)
        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit')
        exitAction.triggered.connect(self.closeEvent)
        self.statusBar()
        menubar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menubar.addMenu('&File')
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)

        exitAction = QAction(QIcon('D:/Programming/Python/mo-mo/GUI/icon/exit.png'), 'Exit', self)
        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAction.triggered.connect(self.closeEvent)

        self.toolbar = self.addToolBar('Exit')
        self.toolbar.addAction(exitAction)

        self.resize(500, 300)
        self.center()
        self.setWindowTitle('Spider')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('D:/Programming/Python/mo-mo/GUI/icon/1.png'))
        self.show()

    def center(self):
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Exit', "Are you sure to quit?", QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No,
                                     QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()


class FormWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(FormWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        QToolTip.setFont(QFont('SansSerif', 10))
        name = QLabel('Selected files:')
        self.file_vulnerability = QLabel('File vulnerability:')
        link_file = QLabel('Link file:')
        network_topology = QLabel('Network topology:')
        start_ip = QLabel('Start IP:')
        file_vulnerabilityEdit = QTextEdit()
        link_fileEdit = QTextEdit()
        network_topologyEdit = QTextEdit()
        start_ipEdit = QLineEdit()
        browse_1 = QPushButton("Display information", self)
        browse_2 = QPushButton("Display information", self)
        browse_3 = QPushButton("Display information", self)
        search = QPushButton("Search", self)
        grid = QGridLayout()
        grid.setSpacing(5)
        grid.addWidget(name, 0, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.file_vulnerability, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(file_vulnerabilityEdit, 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(browse_1, 3, 0)
        grid.addWidget(link_file, 1, 1)
        grid.addWidget(link_fileEdit, 2, 1)
        grid.addWidget(browse_2, 3, 1)
        grid.addWidget(network_topology, 1, 2)
        grid.addWidget(network_topologyEdit, 2, 2)
        grid.addWidget(browse_3, 3, 2)
        grid.addWidget(start_ip, 4, 0)
        grid.addWidget(start_ipEdit, 4, 1)
        grid.addWidget(search, 4, 2)

        self.setLayout(grid)
        self.show()

        search.clicked.connect(run)

        try:
            browse_1.clicked.connect(self.showDialog)
        except Exception as exc:
            print(exc)

    def showDialog(self):
        fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', 'D:/Programming/Python/mo-mo/GUI')[0]

        f = open(fname, 'r')

        with f:
            data = f.read()
            self.file_vulnerabilityEdit.setText(data)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    foo = MyMainWindow()
    foo.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Если закрывается значит ошибка в коде

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поменяйте в коде на:

```
self.file_vulnerabilityEdit = QTextEdit()
```

---

Добавьте в начало кода, что позволит любое пропущенное исключение поймать, включая те, что произошли в слотах `Qt`:

```
import sys
import traceback

def log_uncaught_exceptions(ex_cls, ex, tb):
    text = '{}: {}:\n'.format(ex_cls.__name__, ex)
    text += ''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb))

    QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Error', text)
    sys.exit()

sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions

...

if __name__ == '__main__':
...
```

Comment: Спасибо, очень полезным оказалось..

Comment: Вот что за ошибка                                                                                          > AttributeError: 'Formwidget' object has no attribute 'file_vulnerabilityEdit':File "D:\Programming\Python\mo-mo\GUI/GUI.py", line 112, in showDialog self.file_vulnerabilityEdit.setText(data)

Comment: исходный код добавила, посмотрите пожалуйста, если не трудно

Comment: В FormWidget у вас опять `file_vulnerabilityEdit = QTextEdit()`, но в методе `showDialog` вы к нему обращайтесь через `self.file_vulnerabilityEdit`. В питоне нужно явно указывать в конструкторе что поле относится к классу, используя `self.<название_поля>`. Если мой ответ оказался правильным, то примите его (слева от ответа галочка) и если полезным то поставьте +1 (слева от ответа стрелка вверх)

Comment: @Darkness, просто в питоне нужно явно указывать, поэтому еще в нем в методы классов явно передается ссылка на сам объект (первый аргумент -- `self`)

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте сделать следущее:

```
class FormWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        file_vulnerabilityEdit = QTextEdit()
        browse_1 = QPushButton("Display information", self)
        try:
            browse_1.clicked.connect(showDialog)
        except Exception as exc:
            print(exc)
```

так вы поймёте где ошибка.